# Overlaying normal distribution plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, overlay, normal-distribution

I have two ND curves that I was to plot over one another - how do I do this?

```
#meand and SDs of Gen 1 and 7

mean_gen1 <- 1.241
SD_gen1 <- 1.005
mean_gen7 <- 1.287 
SD_gen7 <- 1.386 

x_gen1 <- seq(-4, 4, length = 1000) * SD_gen1 + mean_gen1
 x_gen7 <- seq(-4, 4, length = 1000) * SD_gen7 + mean_gen7
 y_gen1 <- pnorm(x_gen1, mean_gen1, SD_gen1)
y_gen7 <- pnorm(x_gen7, mean_gen7, SD_gen7)

#plots

gen1_plot <- plot(x_gen1, y_gen1, type="n", xlab = "Height (Meters)", ylab = "", main = "Distribution of Pokemon Heights GEN1", axes = TRUE)+ lines(x_gen1, y_gen1)


gen7_plot <- plot(x_gen7, y_gen7, type="n", xlab = "Height (Meters)", ylab = "", main = "Distribution of Pokemon Heights GEN7", axes = TRUE)+ lines(x_gen7, y_gen7)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your plots are going to be saved in the `gen1_plot` and `gen7_plot` variables. But general base R plotting syntax would be to replace your gen7 `plot()` call with `lines()`, like the following:

```
plot(x_gen1, y_gen1, type="l", 
     xlab = "Height (Meters)", 
     ylab = "", 
     main = "Distribution of Pokemon Heights", 
     axes = TRUE)
lines(x_gen7, y_gen7, col = 2)
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Since your question is tagged with ggplot2, I'll also provide an option for ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
# Put all the data you have in one data.frame
df <- data.frame(x = c(x_gen1, x_gen7),
                 y = c(y_gen1, y_gen7),
                 gen = rep(c("gen1", "gen7"), c(length(x_gen1), length(x_gen7))))

# Plot away
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = gen)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Height (Meters)") +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Pokemon Heights")
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thats great - thank you.
I've ended up with a normal distribution plot (bell curve) I want to add a dashed mean line to each plot - I've tried abline, but that doesn't stop at the end of each curve, it just continues to the top of the graph. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would go for adding the start- and end- x and y positions you want to a new, 4-columned data.frame and use `+ geom_segment(data = that_dataframe, aes(xstart, ystart, xend = xend, yend = yend), linetype = 2)`, for the ggplot version. Not sure about the base R version though.

Comment: Would that work for both plots, as two separate lines?

Comment: Yeah if you would do something like `that_dataframe = data.frame(xstart = c(mean_gen1, mean_gen7), ystart = 0, xend = c(mean_gen1, mean_gen7), yend = 0.5))`. But the means in your first post are quite near each other, so it could appear as 1 line while actually there are 2.